# how to write a unit test to check returned items are of type list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I'm new to unit testing and using MOQ framework with NUnit. I have a controller which returns a list of ViewModel objects as

```
public ActionResult ValidateOutstandingItems()
{
        var entities = _itemsService.GetAll(true).Where(x => x.IsValid == null);
        var model = entities.Select(e => _mappingEngine.Map<ItemModel>(e));
        return View(model);
}
```

I need to write a unit test which will check the returned items from this action method are of type `List<ItemModel>`

I have written something like this

```
[Test]
    public void ValidateOutstandingItemsReturnsItemsViewModelList()
    {            
        var itemsService = new Mock<ItemsService>();
        var mapper = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();
        var itemsList = new List<itemModel>()
        {
            new itemModel{Id = 1,Name = "item 1"},
            new itemModel(){Id=2,Name="item 2"}

        };

        var controller = new ItemController(itemsService.Object, mapper.Object);
        // Act
        var result = controller.ValidateItems();

        // Assert
        var model = ((ViewResult)result).Model as List<ItemModel>;
        Assert.True(model.Count == 2);

    }
```

How can we write the setup method and do the assert to test this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test as written will fail any time, as mocks are not prepared correctly.

Full blown setup will look like:

```
[Test]
public void ValidateOutstandingItemsReturnsItemsViewModelList()
{            
    var itemsService = new Mock<ItemsService>();
    var mapper = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();
    var itemsList = new List<itemModel>()
    {
        new itemModel{Id = 1,Name = "item 1"},
        new itemModel(){Id=2,Name="item 2"}
    };
    itemsService.Setup(s=>s.GetAll(true)).Returns(itemsList);

    var mapped1 = new ItemModel();
    var mapped2 = new ItemModel();

    mapper.Setup(m=>m.Map<ItemModel>(itemList[0])).Returns(mapped1);
    mapper.Setup(m=>m.Map<ItemModel>(itemList[1])).Returns(mapped2);

    var controller = new ItemController(itemsService.Object, mapper.Object);
    // Act
    var result = controller.ValidateItems();

    // Assert
    var model = ((ViewResult)result).Model as List<ItemModel>;
    //Verify that the model contains the 2 mapped elements
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(model, new[]{mapped1, mapped2});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to check whether your model object is null after you use `as List<ItemModel>` cast. If the type is not `List<ItemModel>` it will be null after this statement.

```
[Test]
public void ValidateOutstandingItemsReturnsItemsViewModelList()
{            
    var itemsService = new Mock<ItemsService>();
    var mapper = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();
    var itemsList = new List<itemModel>()
    {
        new itemModel{Id = 1,Name = "item 1"},
        new itemModel(){Id=2,Name="item 2"}

    };

    var controller = new ItemController(itemsService.Object, mapper.Object);
    // Act
    var result = controller.ValidateItems();

    // Assert
    var model = ((ViewResult)result).Model as List<ItemModel>;

    // Test whether type is List<ItemModel>
    Assert.IsNotNull(model, "model is not of type List<ItemModel>");
    Assert.True(model.Count == 2);

}
```

Comment: @NightOwn888 how can we treat or setup `itemsList` as view model

Answer (score 1):

there is method named IsInstanceOfType

```
[Test]
public void ValidateOutstandingItemsReturnsItemsViewModelList()
{            
    var itemsService = new Mock<ItemsService>();
    var mapper = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();
    var itemsList = new List<itemModel>()
    {
        new itemModel{Id = 1,Name = "item 1"},
        new itemModel(){Id=2,Name="item 2"}

    };

    var controller = new ItemController(itemsService.Object, mapper.Object);
    // Act
    var result = controller.ValidateItems();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(((ViewResult)result).Model, typeof(List<ItemModel>));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your implementation above, but I think you will figure it out (it could be typos when you typed questions). You mentioned the controller return a list of ViewModel (ItemViewModel) objects and Service returns list of model object to controller (ItemModel), having said that to set up the mock object you could try something like:

```
        // Setup itemService GetAll like this
        itemsService.Setup(m => m.GetAll(It.Is(true))).Returns(itemsList.ToArray());

        mapper.Setup(m => m.Map<ItemModel[], ItemViewModel[]>(It.IsAny<ItemModel[]>()))
            .Returns(itemViewModelList.ToArray());
```

To assert:

```
        // Act
        var result = controller.ValidateOutstandingItems() as ViewResult;

        // Check number of items are correct
        var model = result.Model as List<ItemViewModel>;
        Assert.True(model.Count == 2);
```

You will have to create itemList and itemViewModelList in the unit test.